# Adjusting custom list column widths

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I would like to adjust the column widths in a custom list in Sharepoint 2013.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: @that dweeb in the corner: Thank you! Needed a simple workaround for a transitionary list...extended column by adding underscores. Sorry don't have reputation worthy of up ticking. I hope someone does.

Answer (score 6):

1. Open SharePoint Designer, and then click on the SharePoint site with the list to edit.
2. Click "Lists" in the left navigation pane and then click the list to edit in SharePoint Designer.
3. The way has a little complex. Since changing the column width with SharePoint Designer 2013 refers to changing the CSS codes.

[Source](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/t/177792.aspx)

Have a look at the below link,

[Change the width of SharePoint List column](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/07512437-fecf-4257-bcc8-ba3c8e467554/how-to-increase-width-of-a-list-in-sharepoint-designer-2013)

Comment: Thanks, but this link is for 2010 solution.

Comment: No, its for SP 2013 and its under "SharePoint forums ->  
SharePoint 2013 - Using SharePoint Designer, InfoPath and Other Customizations"

Answer (score 2):

Use this javascript in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("TH.ms-vh2:contains('Column Name')").css("width", "300px"); //You can change the Column Name to be the column you want to change the width, Title in the code for example.
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the less aspx-confident users, a simple lateral fix is available.
Go to the online list, then open Quick Edit in the List menu. Highlight the offending column, select "Rename" from the invisible dropdown arrow to the right of the field, and either add some innocuous-looking explanatory text to the title, or throw as many underscores, or other non-threatening special characters, at it as are required to reduce the vertiginously wrapped look of the text.

If you want to shrink column width, it's still character dependent, so you may need to abbreviate the column title.