# Increase column width in a Document Library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, web-part, document-library, script

I am looking for a way to increase the column width in a document library.  Found a lot of ways to get this done by changing XSLT [Changing Column Width](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83159/adjusting-custom-list-column-widths)

But I am looking for a way to change by page level using a script editor web part.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code in a content/script editor webpart. Change the name of the column. I see the max-width of the column is set to 500px. So if you want to make your column width more than 500px, then you have to change the max-width, otherwise that is not needed.
I ran this code on SharePoint online and it worked fine.

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    var columnName = 'MyColumn';
    var element = $("div[name='" + columnName + "']").parent();
    var width = '600px';
    element.css('max-width', width);
    element.css('width', width) 
}); 
</script>
```